# MPMoviePlayerController reconnecting multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

I have a simple HTTP server running that pretty much just serves an MP3 file in chunks of equal size. I'm writing an iOS app (for testing purposes), that basically takes a URL and streams the file through `MPMovieController`. Here's my sample code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
mp.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080"];
[mp play];
```

It works. BUT: on my http server I see multiple connections (first one breaks right away, second one streams to the end usually, although sometimes there is 3rd connection).

I know it's not the server issue, since when I do this:

`NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080"]];`

...then there's only 1 connection that finishes reading and disconnects.

The question is: Why does MPMoviePlayerController need to establish and break those connections before finishing reading the file, why doesn't it just keep waiting for more data to be written on the socket? I haven't been able to find any relevant docs that would explain this :(

P.S. If you are curious why I need this, here's a short explanation: I'm trying to emulate real life network scenarios where bytes are received by the MPMovieController in chunks with small delays of random length in between

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS development at all, so take this with a pound of salt... but have you considered that the `MPMoviePlayerController` might be reconnecting as it doesn't have enough data to keep playing?  I am also curious about the time between the reconnects, and their relation to the chunks sent.  Does the problem lessen or go away entirely when you use much larger chunks?  Can you post a packet capture, so we can see if there is anything weird about this stream?

Comment: Brad, thank you for direction. I'm gonna check things you have mentioned and hopefully derive a conclusion that makes sense. I'll post back with the details soon

Comment: Another thing to check is make sure the stream isn't horribly corrupt.  If you are dropping a byte here or there, it will be difficult for the player to sync to the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your server and add support for `HTTP 206 Partial Content` requests/responses. iOS requests movie data over HTTP this way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had to end up doing... I was hoping to minimise/simplify the server but the movie controller insists on asking for byte ranges. Thanks for the confirmation Jonathan